# Regions and their combinations

Tags: regions

I met stupid problems playing with combinations of simple 3D regions. Can anyboby explain what is wrong in my code?

I need to make a model for 3D-printing.

```
RegionPlot3D[{
  Cuboid[{-3, -27, 0}, {-6, -50, 25}],
  Cuboid[{-5, -41, 0}, {-20, -38, 25}],
  Prism[{{-27, -38, 0}, {-19, -38, 0}, {-19, -45, 0}, {-27, -38, 
     25}, {-19, -38, 25}, {-19, -45, 25}}],
  rg1,
  Cuboid[{-3, 27, 0}, {-6, 50, 25}],
  Cuboid[{-5, 41, 0}, {-20, 38, 25}],
  Prism[{{-27, 38, 0}, {-19, 38, 0}, {-19, 45, 0}, {-27, 38, 
     25}, {-19, 38, 25}, {-19, 45, 25}}]},
 PlotPoints -> 81,
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"},
 PlotRange -> {{-60, 60}, {-60, 60}, {0, 27}}]
```

where the `rg1` is 3D-arc:

```
rg1=RegionIntersection[
      RegionDifference[
       Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 25}}, 30],
       Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 25}}, 27]],
      Cuboid[{-6, -30, 0}, {30, 30, 25}]
      ];
```

Generally, it looks like following:

[image]

However, I need the joint region to make the stl-file. Thus, I've tried the `RegionUnion` to combine the elements. However, it is not so easy:

Making the clamps, I found that simple

```
RegionUnion[
Cuboid[{-3, -27, 0}, {-6, -50, 25}],
Cuboid[{-5, -41, 0}, {-20, -38, 25}],
Prism[{{-27, -38, 0}, {-19, -38, 0}, {-19, -45, 
          0}, {-27, -38, 25}, {-19, -38, 25}, {-19, -45, 25}}]
]
```

produces an error-message:

> RegionBounds::reg: Cuboid[{-3,-27,0},{-6,-50,25}] is not a correctly
>   specified region.

Ok, I've tried following:

```
rc1=RegionUnion[
  Region@Cuboid[{-3, -27, 0}, {-6, -50, 25}],
  Region@Cuboid[{-5, -41, 0}, {-20, -38, 25}],
  Region@Prism[{{-27, -38, 0}, {-19, -38, 0}, {-19, -45, 
      0}, {-27, -38, 25}, {-19, -38, 25}, {-19, -45, 25}}]
  ];
rc2 = RegionUnion[
Region@Cuboid[{-3, 27, 0}, {-6, 50, 25}],
Region@Cuboid[{-5, 41, 0}, {-20, 38, 25}],
Region@
Prism[{{-27, 38, 0}, {-19, 38, 0}, {-19, 45, 0}, {-27, 38, 25}, {-19, 38, 25}, {-19, 45, 25}}]
];
```

It works good, making the separate clamps like following without errors:

[image]

But when I try to combine the whole model I again met the errors:
`RegionPlot3D[{rg1, rc1, rc2}]`

> RegionPlot3D::nnregion:
>   Region[BooleanRegion[#1||#2||#3&,{Cuboid[{-3,-27,0},{-6,-50,25}],Cuboid[{-5,-41,0},{-20,-38,25}],Prism[{{-27,-38,0},{-19,-38,0},{-19,-45,0},{-27,-38,25},{-19,-38,25},{-19,-45,25}}]}]]
>   cannot be automatically discretized.
>
> RegionPlot3D::invplotreg:
>   {BooleanRegion[#1&&!#2&&#3&,{Cylinder[{{0,0,0},{0,0,25}},30],Cylinder[{{0,0,0},{0,0,25}},27],Cuboid[{-6,-30,0},{30,30,25}]}],Region[BooleanRegion[#1||#2||#3&,{<<1>>}]],Region[BooleanRegion[#1||#2||#3&,{Cuboid[{-3,27,0},{-6,50,25}],Cuboid[{-5,41,0},{-20,38,25}],Prism[{{-27,38,0},{-19,38,0},{-19,45,0},{-27,38,25},{-19,38,25},{-19,45,25}}]}]]}
>   is not a valid region to plot.
>
> RegionPlot3D::argr: RegionPlot3D called with 1 argument; 4 arguments
>   are expected.

When I try the `RegionUnion[rc1,rg1,rc2]`, it gives me following:

```
Region[
BooleanRegion[Or[#, #2, #3, 
And[#4, 
Not[#5], #6], #7, #8, #9]& , {
Cuboid[{-3, -27, 0}, {-6, -50, 25}], 
Cuboid[{-5, -41, 0}, {-20, -38, 25}], 
Prism[{{-27, -38, 0}, {-19, -38, 0}, {-19, -45, 0}, {-27, -38, 
    25}, {-19, -38, 25}, {-19, -45, 25}}], 
Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 25}}, 30], 
Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 25}}, 27], 
Cuboid[{-6, -30, 0}, {30, 30, 25}], 
Cuboid[{-3, 27, 0}, {-6, 50, 25}], 
Cuboid[{-5, 41, 0}, {-20, 38, 25}], 
Prism[{{-27, 38, 0}, {-19, 38, 0}, {-19, 45, 0}, {-27, 38, 25}, {-19, 
    38, 25}, {-19, 45, 25}}]}]]
```

but it does not produce a normal 3D-region.

What is wrong with these 3D primitives?

Comment: Do they meet at an exact plane? Sometimes you have to mush the two regions into each other by a tiny bit. For example, if `RegionUnion[{Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}], 
  Cuboid[{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 2}]}]` didn't work, you'd squash them together like this `RegionUnion[{Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}], 
  Cuboid[{0, 0, 0.9999}, {1, 1, 2}]}]`  By the way your _first_ bit of code for the clamp worked for me on v12.1.1.0 and I got a correct looking `Polyhedron` object back, so you're probably experiencing a bug in an older version. .

Comment: @flinty, as I understood, you mean the presence of the invisible gaps between pieces of Region? My code makes them touching without overlapping but without gaps too. May be the microgaps appears during the inner processing of the 3D primitives due to numerical errors, I don't know.

Comment: No I mean even if they're touching perfectly _without_ gaps it can go wrong. You should make them touch and overlap by a very tiny amount (which you may need to experiment with).